# CircuitBreakException <transport_request> Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, g1gc

My setup is 1 master node and 18 data node.My master node also data node.My tps events/sec 70-100 and my jvm options like this.

Elasticsearch version 7.5.0
open-jdk 13

Active primary shards : 5404
Active shards : 10064

Machines has a 32 GB Memory. And i got an error when insert and searchs.
I checked logs and see circuit break exceptions 'Data too large for <transport_request> larger than limit. '

```
## JVM configuration

################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## You should always set the min and max JVM heap
## size to the same value. For example, to set
## the heap to 4 GB, set:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms24g
-Xmx24g

################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below this section are considered
## expert settings. Don't tamper with them unless
## you understand what you are doing
##
################################################################

## GC configuration
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

## JDK 8 GC logging

8:-XX:+PrintGCDetails
8:-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
8:-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
8:-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
8:-Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log
8:-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
8:-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32
8:-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m

# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

How can i decrease heap on machines ?

Comment: Which machine reported the "Data too large" exception?

Comment: All machines getting same error.

Comment: Try increasing jvm heap size.

Comment: Ty my friend. :)